# Javascript - Clipping image diagonally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've come to a tough problem to day as I was assigned a HTML5 projects.

The project includes moving a picture on a inclined slope. I'll demonstrate this in the picture below
[image: demo]

As you can see, I want to move Obama's picture from A to B on the slope AB. And while moving, the picture is cropped and limited by the line AB. The line AB is actually the lower edge of a PNG image.

[image: demo]

Best regards.

Comment: You can animate the position of the picture from left to right and keep Obama's picture behind the white "slope" with z-index. Use absolute positioning. It's not hard at all; use jQuery.

Comment: There is no question (nor code) in here.

Comment: @frenchie I thought so too, at first, but it's the *lower* edge of a picture. I don't think a pure `z-index` solution will be enough.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of what you have done in [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: use HTML5 Canvas for this...

Comment: Instead of your parallelogram, just do a right triangle ABC with C being your bottom-right corner. Here's for the triangle: http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles

Comment: @frenchie but the problem is that AB is the lower edge of the parallelogram. You could imagine it **a smaller picture moves inside a bigger frame with parallelogram shape**

Comment: @SaurabhLP: ok I'll try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try doing this with some transforms :

The idea is to rotate an outside box and include an image, then rotate the image inside.

Demo : http://jsbin.com/ozusic/1/edit

CSS :

```
  @keyframes "move" {
   0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
      -moz-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
      -o-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
      -ms-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
      transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
   }
   100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
      -moz-transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
      -o-transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
      -ms-transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
      transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
   }

  }

  @-moz-keyframes move {
   0% {
     -moz-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
     transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
   }
   100% {
     -moz-transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
     transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
   }

  }

  @-webkit-keyframes "move" {
   0% {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
     transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
   }
   100% {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
     transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
   }

  }

  @-ms-keyframes "move" {
   0% {
     -ms-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
     transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
   }
   100% {
     -ms-transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
     transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
   }

  }

  @-o-keyframes "move" {
   0% {
     -o-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
     transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(10deg);
   }
   100% {
     -o-transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
     transform: translateX(500px) translateY(70px) rotate(10deg);
   }

  }

  img {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      position: absolute;

      -webkit-animation: 5s move infinite;
      -moz-animation: 5s move infinite;
      -ms-animation: 5s move infinite;
      -o-animation: 5s move infinite;
      animation: 5s move infinite;
      z-index: -1;
  }

  div.box {
      margin-top: 50px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 3px solid black;

      -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      transform: rotate(-10deg);
      overflow: hidden;
  }
```

HTML :

```
<div class='box'>
   <img src='http://www.biography.com/imported/images/Biography/Images/Profiles/O/Barack-Obama-12782369-2-402.jpg' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, you're brilliant, this is the solution I've been looking for

Answer (score 2):

Here's the HTML and CSS setup:

```
#TheImage{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:20px;
    z-index:1;}

#TheTriangle{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 200px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 800px solid blue;
    top:100px;
    left:15px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;}

    <img id="TheImage" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <div id="TheTriangle"></div>
```

You can take a look at it here on this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2w75U/1/)** Now all you have to do is adjust dimensions, change the triangle to white and use jQuery's `.animate()` function to change the image's left position: just a few lines of code. Since this is YOUR homework, I think it's best if we leave it here for now and check back after you've struggled a bit... This is a very good homework question BTW.

[image]

And here the javascript to make it work along with the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2w75U/3/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('#TheImage').animate({'left':600}, 2000);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but there'll be a blue box that can not be set transparent

Comment: No, I believe you're not thinking: it can be set to white! I put it in blue so that you could see the HTML setup. This solution is the answer your teacher is looking for BTW.

Comment: I've thought of that actually. I can not set it to white because the **web background itself has color, too** ! But setting the color to transparent will not work

Comment: Well then just add 1 line of code to get the background color and 1 line to set that color to the triangle; 2 more lines of code and you're done. Thought of that?

Comment: While you are correct; you can either get and set the color using JS, or simply set the border to the same color as the web background in CSS... you should have just edited your answer to incorporate those options. Your current comments make you sound like kind of a condescending douchebag, which hopefully wasn't what you were going for. (The fact that this answer is 4 years old, doesn't change that. This is an internet community, things are meant to last here.)