# Show only half of the image or crop it diagonally with Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, z-index, crop

i want to build a mobile tool in phonegap with Javascript to show people how their shower flagging will look like. The user should take a picture with the camera to show it in the app. To understand what i´m talking about take a look at this:

[image]

These 3 images should fit together. It works perfectly if i use the fitted images with transparent background. The problem is, if i take a picture with the camera of the device it will be a square picture.

So it will look like this:

[image]

My HTML Code for the images:

```
<div id="Images">

   <div id="wand"><img id="imageTop" src="images/top.png"> </div>
   <div id="boden"><img id="imageMid" src="images/mid.png"> </div>
   <div id="rinne"><img id="imageBottom" src="images/bottom.png"> </div>
 </div>
```

In my js code i just set the new image as src of e.g imageTop like that:

```
   var image = document.getElementById('imageTop');
   image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

Now of course i can set the z-index of image 2 and 3 lower than the 1. image, so a taken picture for imageTop will work, because it is in the background. The problem is, it shall be possible to take 2 pictures, for image 1 and for image 2, so i have two new "half" images in my app. Just image 3 remains the same. Can i crop the image diagonally with javascript or make it transparent, so it will fit?

I hope you understand my problem. Please help me i don´t know how i can do this :/

Comment: It's not clear: which image is user-generated and which images are always the same? top.png or bottom.png? Take a look here for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477984/javascript-clipping-image-diagonally

Comment: Image 1 and Image 2 are user generated with the camera. Image 3 always remains the same, saw this post already but i don´t want to show a single image, i need a saved image which i can use

Comment: Then take a look at the answer I wrote on the question; basically, you need a div with Image1 and a triangle that overlaps the bottom of the image, a div with Image2 and another triangle and then a div with Image3 and 2 triangles. Then, put these 3 divs in a div with overflow hidden and it should work fine. BTW, what are the dimensions of the images and of the container? Also, can you put image3 in a jsfiddle? Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/2w75U/4/

Comment: Hey that sounds like a good idea. What do you mean with "can you put image3 in a jsfiddle?" Only the .png file of the middle image?

Comment: So i just leave out the animation and do this with all 3 images? I think the dimensions are insignificant, they are all responsive(100%) to fit for the app..

Comment: How can i realize this in percentage values? Can´t figure it out -.-

Comment: I recommend you first do a version with fixed-width dimensions (ie. the whole structure is 500px by 500px) and then, when you've got is working, you check and see where to make changes so that it works in %. And please put the .png of the middle image in a fiddle too.